# sorting a listbox in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a listbox with values. Now I need to sort that listbox, BUT NOT BY ALPHABETICALLY.

You see the values in a listbox are from a table.

```
------------------------
| name | order |  size |
========================
 value1   4
 value2   3
 value3   1 
 value4   2
```

I hope I made myself clear. So the list box has the items "value1, value2, value3, value4". I want it to sort by the order declared in the table. The list box has nothing to do with the table and is not "data bound" to it. The values come from somewhere else.

Tech used: VBA, Access 2007

Comment: Got any code already? Or you just want some homework done? ;-)

Comment: It's not really homework. I am at work with a flu, and my head is killing me. It's not even listed in the requirements they gave me, but I know the boss is going to want sorting. Basically it forms a select statement out of these values. 

Select value1, value2.. and if they are out of order, then the final report being spit out is all out of order..

Comment: My alternative is to just give them up/down buttons so they can move the listbox items themselves however they want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the *Row Source Type* for your list box is "Value List".  Since the values come from a table, change *Row Source Type* to "Table/Query", then use a query for *Row Source*:

```
SELECT [name], [order]
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY [order];
```

You don't have to display [order] in the list box ... set its column width to zero.

Your list box control does not have to be bound to a data source field for this approach to work.  If the list box is unbound, the user selection will not be stored, but the list box will still allow users to make selections from the list box.

Notice I enclosed [name] and [order] in square brackets because both are reserved words.  See [Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html)

Comment: Thankyou, Unfortunately I can not do that as the user is allowed to move/add/delete stuff from the listbox. Calling Additem/RemoveItem with a listbox with "Table/Query" produces an error.

Comment: When the user adds an item to the list, does it get stored in the table which contains the other list values?  If not, how do you assign [order] for the new item?  Just place it at the end?

Comment: User can only add specific items (from another listbox, but that is irrelevant). So he has buttons like " > ", " >> ", " < ", " << " to move items around. 

The items intially come from another table BUT these items are the COLUMN NAMES from the other table. Do you get what I mean?

Table1's column names are the entries for Table 2.

Comment: When the user adds an item to the list box, does that item value get stored in Table 2?  Or any other table?

Comment: No sir. However, I think i've found an alternative. Thankyou for your time, and enjoy the marked answer!

Comment: I don't really have a solution for this. I would post it if I did. I went for another alternative route instead (allowing the user to move the items in the listbox up/down so they can sort however they want)

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim First           As Integer
Dim Last            As Integer
Dim a               As Integer
Dim b               As Integer
Dim Temp            As String
Dim test()          As String

First = LBound(test)
Last = UBound(test)
For a = First To Last - 1
    For b = a + 1 To Last
        If test(a) > test(b) Then
            Temp = test(b)
            test(b) = test(a)
            test(a) = Temp
        End If
    Next b
Next a

For a = 1 To UBound(test)

    lst_email.AddItem test(a) 'lst_email is a listbox

Next
```